# Uniform continuity of function v continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

I need to show that a function $f: [1, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) =  x^{-1} $ is uniformly continuous.

If I let $ \delta = \epsilon $ and $ | x - a | < \delta $,
$ |f(x) - f(a)| =  |x^{-1} - a^{-1}| = |\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{a}| = \frac{|a-x|}{|ax|} < \frac{\delta}{|ax|} \le \delta = \epsilon$ as $a$ and $x$ are larger than or equal to one (domain). This demonstrates that $$|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$$
I believe this shows that the function is continuous but I don't know what constitutes uniform continuity, or what I need to show to demonstrate that it is uniformly continuous. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should notice that in the usual definition of continuity, $\delta$ depends on both $\varepsilon$ and a certain point $x_{0}$. The $\delta$ you wrote is independent of the fixed point (in this case written as) $a$, thus uniformly continuity is proven.

Comment: Some visual help for an intuitive understanding of the concept https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Visualization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already proved uniform continuity. If your $\delta$ depended on $a$ then you would just have continuity at $a$. But since it is independent of $a$ you have proved uniform continuity.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to write it slightly better. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, choose $\delta=\epsilon$. Now let $x$ and $y$ be in $[1, \infty )$, doing the same you have done, whenever $|x-y|<\delta,$ we get $| f(x) - f(y)| <\epsilon$. As you probably noticed, this is exactly uniform continuity definition.